# How to rename/revise target file with version number on installing in CMake?

Tags: cmake, installation, version, lib, kdevelop

I'm using CMake-3.13.4 and KDevelop-5.2.1.

I have a topmost CMakeLists.txt that defines the version numbers of my target.
It looks like:

```
set( PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR 1 )
set( PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR 4 )
set( PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH 7 )
...
add_executable( mytarget main.cpp XXX.cpp ... )
target_link_libraries( mytarget "stdc++fs" ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ... )
install( TARGETS mytarget RUNTIME DESTINATION . )
```

I want CMake automatically append the version string to the file name of the target. So I code as following:

```
install( TARGETS mytarget RUNTIME DESTINATION . RENAME "mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}" )
```

But it doesn't work.

Is there a way it can be done with CMake?
The file name I finally want is "mytarget-1.4.7".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for the property [`OUTPUT_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/prop_tgt/OUTPUT_NAME.html).

```
add_executable( mytarget main.cpp XXX.cpp ... )
target_link_libraries( mytarget "stdc++fs" ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ... )
set_target_properties( mytarget PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH}" ) 
install( TARGETS mytarget RUNTIME DESTINATION . )
```

Comment: `OUTPUT_NAME` has limited usage: you can't use it to specify same name as another target, otherwise `MSVC` build fails. `MSVC` creates `${OUTPUT_NAME}.lib` for each target and it may conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I got it by modifying codes as following:

```
add_executable( mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH} 
 main.cpp XXX.cpp ... )

target_link_libraries( mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH} "stdc++fs" ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ... )

install( TARGETS mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH} RUNTIME DESTINATION . )
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate an install target with custom name, I let CMake run custom code during install. The custom code just calls `file(COPY ...)` - in my case, in order to install a `libcalf.so` as `calf.so`:

```
install(
    CODE "file(COPY $<TARGET_FILE:calf>/ DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/lv2/${PROJECT_NAME}.lv2/calf.so)"
)
```

In your example, I guess the equivalent answer would be

```
install(
    CODE "file(COPY $<TARGET_FILE:mytarget>/ DESTINATION ./mytarget-${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_PATCH})"
)
```